# irreducibility of a tensor product of two irreducible representations

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

This is a follow-up question to Chaturvedi's question and Rickard's reply
--- see [Representations irreducible with respect to the tensor product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377454/representations-irreducible-with-respect-to-the-tensor-product?newreg=652c7e9acab94cdd85eb3cf232d5b3dc)

*Question:* Suppose $U$ and $V$ are two irreducible complex representations of a finite group $G$ such that the tensor product $U \otimes V$
is also irreducible. Must it be the case that either $U$
or $V$ (or both) are one dimensional ?

Thanks, Ines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? Take groups $H_1$ and $H_2$ with irreps $U_1$ and $U_2$.
Let $G=H_1\times H_2$. Regard $U_i$ as a $G$-representation by pulling
back the $H_i$-action to $G$ via the projection $G\to H_i$. I reckon
then $U_1$, $U_2$ and $U_1\otimes U_2$ will all be irreps of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an example where $ U $ and $ V $ are faithful then you can take $ U $ and $ V $ to be the two distinct irreps of dimension $ 2 $ of $ 2.A_5 $. Then their tensor product $ U \otimes V $ is a 4d irrep of $ 2.A_5 $ (the one lifted from the 4d irrep of $ A_5 $).

Comment: What does the notation $2.A_5$ mean?

Comment: @JeanneScott it is the double cover of the alternating group, see https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Double_cover_of_alternating_group or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_groups_of_the_alternating_and_symmetric_groups . In particular $ 2.A_5 $ is the unique perfect central extension of $ A_5 $, what is known as the Schur cover of $ A_5 $. There is also a well known exceptional isomorphism $ 2.A_5 \cong SL(2,5) $ if you like matrix groups over finite fields

Comment: Is this 4-dimensional representation a Weyl representation of $\mathrm{SL}(2,5)$ with respect to some multiplicative character $\chi$ of $\Bbb{F}_{5^2}$ ?