# Can an irrep be a tensor product of representations

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, physics

Consider a unitary irrep of a compact Lie Group $G$ onto a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, $\pi\colon G\to\mathcal U(\mathcal H)$. Now assume that $\mathcal H$ can be decomposed into a tensor product, $\mathcal H=V\otimes W$. Is it possible that $V$ and $W$ are also representaions of $G$?

In other words, can a unitary irrep be decomposed into a tensor product of (reudcible or not) representations? Maybe exluding one-dimensional tensor factors?

Edit: Note that I don't want to assume more than compactness of the Lie group $G$, in particular no direct product struture...

Comment: e.g. if $G=K\times L$ and if $L$ acts trivially on $V$ and $L$ trivially on $W$ and $V,W$ are irreps of $K,L$ respectively

Comment: Does this answer your question? [irreducibility of a tensor product of two irreducible representations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389889/irreducibility-of-a-tensor-product-of-two-irreducible-representations)

Comment: In both cases I would need to know more about the structure of $G$ (that it is the direct product of two groups), which ideally I don't want to assume...

Comment: @Alex: that link answers your question as stated ("yes, it is possible"). Do you have a different question in mind? E.g. are you asking "is it possible for *every* compact Lie group $G$"? (The answer to that question is no, e.g. this doesn't happen for $G = SU(2)$.)

Comment: You're right, @QiaochuYuan, it does indeed answer the questionas I posted it. Do you have more info for groups it doesn't happen? Or any idea for literature on this? That would be super-helpful!

Comment: There is something interesting in your phrasing. You start with a pre-existing tensor product structure on $H$ and ask if it is possible that the tensor factors $V$ and $W$ are also representation. If we drop the whole issue of irreducibility the answer is yes by the oldest trick in the book of 'flipping the order in which you obtain your object': instead of starting with the representation on $H$ we start with representations on $V$ and $W$ and they automatically give an representation  on $V \otimes W$ and we can *define* $\pi$ like that. But this leaves the question of : (ctd in next cmt)

Comment: 'Given a very concrete description of $\pi$, how can we easily check if it is of this form, i.e. a tensor product of two smaller representations? Maybe that is what you are really after for some concrete case? I don't think there is a general answer, but in concrete cases a beautiful answer might be possible.

Comment: Something else I noted in your question: when we have representations $\rho, \sigma$ on $V$ and on $W$ the represetation $\pi$ on $V \times W$ is given by $\pi(g)(v \otimes w) := \rho(g)v \otimes \sigma(g)w$, so the element $g$ acts on both tensor factors. Because of your references to product groups you were maybe perhaps more thinking about a construction where some elements of $G$ *only* act on one tensor factor and some only on the other? (EDIT: I see now that the answer in the linked question is somethat of that form. Maybe you are asking of examples NOT of that form exist?)

Comment: The question really is: given $H$ and a representation of $\pi\colon G\to H$, under what condition could $\pi$ be of the form $\rho\otimes\sigma$, and in particular if $\pi$ is irreducible. @QiaochuYuan mentioned that this is not posible for $G=SU(2)$, I wonder for what groups this is also not possible and/or how to even show it in the case of $SU(2)$ so that maybe I can find it out myself for other groups... From the link I get that it is not possible if the groups have a direct product strucutre that would allow for irreps of the subgroups $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that $U_1\otimes U_2=H$

Answer (score 3):

As the commentors on to the question have rightly pointed out, the quesiton as it is posed is indeed answered by [irreducibility of a tensor product of two irreducible representations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389889/irreducibility-of-a-tensor-product-of-two-irreducible-representations). Thanks, @user10354138 and @QiaochuYuan.